# display external webpage inside shiny through a POST request

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to put a button on my shiny app which calls out external website though a form/post request.  The input values will change but here is a real example.

```
Example:
<form action="http://toppgene.cchmc.org/CheckInput.action" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="query" value="TOPPFUN">
<input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="HGNC">
<input type="hidden" name="training_set" id="training_set" value="EGFR">
<input type="submit" class="mybutton">
</form>
```

PS: cross posted on shiny-discuss google group [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/uVIZ64pvABI)

Thanks!
-Abhi

Comment: What is your question?  What happens? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Well I want to embed this form inside shiny where the "training_set" value can change based on the user selected options and when the user pressed the submit button the page retrieved by form action could be displayed

Comment: When put this into an HTML file and click on the submit button it takes you to another webpage. So if you want that page shown in a Shiny app you would need to use an iframe. I would suggest you start with a basic html page and see if you can pass some inputs to the site. If that works try to convert to a Shiny app and ask questions  if you get stuck.